# Search between two date ranges

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a car rental system, and in this page people can make car reservations.

So I need to know how can I search using the date range from the client (rent out and return) in the booking table.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `autos_bookings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `auto_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_out` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_return` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `autos_bookings`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `autos_bookings`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

So, what I would like to do, is to have another range of dates (for the example, let's say: `$dateclientewantsrent` and `$dateclientewantsreturn`) and search in that table if there is any existing booking.

```
SELECT * FROM `autos_bookings` WHERE SOMETHING
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP other than that you have to remember to use prepared statements. Could you remove the PHP part and focus on MySQL part only?

Comment: If its possible, I need the complete PHP command, not only the MySQL query, that's why I'm adding the PHP

Comment: There's nothing you need to do on PHP side. You already have the code that can execute some SQL query. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Two ranges overlaps when each range start is less then opposite range end. I.e.

```
...
WHERE booking.date_out < $date_cliente_wants_rent
  AND $date_cliente_wants_return < booking.date_return
...
```

Depends on the logic one or both compares may be weak.