# Select data between a given interval of time from two columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to retrieve data from a table from a given interval of time. My table is like this -

| id | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06:30:00 | 07:00:00 |
| 2 | 06:45:00 | 07:15:00 |
| 3 | 13:15:00 | 14:00:00 |
| 4 | 09:30:00 | 10:15:00 |

Given interval of time - (05:00:00 - 10:00:00)

My Expectation -

| id | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06:30:00 | 07:00:00 |
| 2 | 06:45:00 | 07:15:00 |
| 4 | 09:30:00 | 10:15:00 |

I need to get the id (4) as its start time in the given interval of time.
So what will be the query?

so far I can imagine this -

[image: pls see the image]

Comment: "So what will be the query?" - So what have you tried ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72991179/10138734

Comment: @VBoka I have updated the description with the image, pls have a look.

Comment: @MohammadSheam why is id 4 in your expected result, it is not between (05:00:00 - 10:00:00 interval

Comment: @ErgestBasha id 4 start time is less than 10:00

Comment: Hi @VBoka, yes seems like I am getting my expected result. need to test with a different scenario.

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE  

 ('05:00:00' BETWEEN start_time AND end_time) OR (start_time BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '10:00:00')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the values between the given interval of time - (05:00:00 - 10:00:00) use:

```
select * 
from tbl
where Start_Time between '05:00:00' and '10:00:00'
or End_Time  between '05:00:00' and '10:00:00';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba828afe1a3ca9f21d6c104ea7dcfdff

Using comparison operator

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE  
(`start_time`>= '05:00:00' AND `start_time` <= '10:00:00') OR 
 (`end_time`>= '05:00:00' AND `end_time` <= '10:00:00')
```

Comment: This is not correct because OP says: "I need to get the id (4) as its start time in the given interval of time."

Comment: I am still not sure if OP wants the records with start time before interval and end time inside interval... I have removed my downvote...

Comment: OP did not provided example where the start time is out of the interval and end time inside of the interval.

Comment: thanks, @ErgestBasha, I was thinking a similar kind of way. but  BETWEEN is inclusive. If there is a case that has to be exclusive, then I think I need to replace it with two comparisons.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE  
(start_time>= '05:00:00' AND start_time <= '10:00:00') OR 
 (end_time>= '05:00:00' AND end_time <= '10:00:00') `

is working now. thanks